# Updating postgres with if conditions on parameters

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am trying to do a postgres update using if conditions to check if a parameter is empty before attempting to update.

The desired result would be not to update when the parameter is an ampty string.

I cannot seem to figure out the correct way to do this. My first attempt is below:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
  UPDATE users SET
    fname = IF(trim(:fname) = '', fname, :fname)
  WHERE username = :username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fname);
$stmt->execute();
```

and then my second attempt was using:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
  UPDATE users SET fname =
    IF
      trim(:fname) =  ''
    THEN
      fname
    ELSE
      :fname
    END IF;
  WHERE username = :username
");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fname);
$stmt->execute();
```

What is the correct way of doing this with IF statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Probably the best way would be not to execute the statement; the PHP code already knows that the parameter is empty, so it can refrain from calling the `$stmt->execute()` (and surrounding code). That will also save the round-trip time to the database.

  ```php
  if (trim($fname) != "") {
     $stmt = $db->prepare("
        UPDATE users
        SET fname = :fname
        WHERE username = :username");
     $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
     $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fname);
     $stmt->execute();
  }
  ```
- If you do need to have the condition in the PostgreSQL query, note that `IF` is a statement, not an expression. The equivalent for expressions is `CASE`, something like:

  ```sql
  UPDATE users
  SET fname = CASE WHEN trim(:fname) = '' THEN fname ELSE :fname END
  WHERE username = :username
  ```
- In this particular case, you can also put the condition as part of the `WHERE` clause:

  ```sql
  UPDATE users
  SET fname = :fname
  WHERE username = :username and trim(:fname) <> ''
  ```

Comment: Note: there was a contribution from someone else (now deleted) which pointed out that there's a bug/feature in (some versions of?) the PHP database bindings where each bound parameter can only be used once; as such, in the options where `:fname` is used twice, we would instead have to use `:fname1` and `:fname2` and make sure we pass the same value for both parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI on the note by @sabik. If you face this condition consider rewriting the query in such a way that the parameter(s) is passed into a CTE, the CTE is then used for the expression. So for the current statement perhaps something like:

```
with params (username, fname) as
   ( values (':username', ':fname') )
update users
   set name = fname
  from params
 where username = username 
   and trim(fname) <> '';
```

It may not always be doable, but it's worth a look. Especially if the parameter is used several times and there are several parameters. It avoids the 'coordination' of matching values, and getting them in the correct order. You just have to get them in the correct order individually and just once. Additionally, when the query itself exists in a function/procedure, you can change the query to use the same parameter(s) in any order provided you do not change the CTE. And then you do not need to change the calling routines at all.